# Foreach loop in make:request rules() laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to validate the business name and email to avoid duplicate entries.
Here's what I got so far

```
public function rules()
{
    $businesses = Business::all();
    foreach ($businesses as $business) {
        return [
        'name' => 'unique:businesses,name,' . $business->id,
        'email' => 'email|unique:businesses,email,' . $business->id,
        'logo' => 'file|size:5000,' . $business->id,
        'banner' => 'file|size:5000,' . $business->id,
        ];  
    } 
}
```

but it still returns this error

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Comment: `return` in a loop will stop/exit the loop after the first iteration. And shouldn't you validate a `request` instead of all business models?

Comment: No need foreach and no need to call `$businesses = Business::all();`,  here `unique:businesses,name` **businesses** is the table name and, **name** is the field.

Comment: maybe that's what I am doing wrong. so what should I do to make it happen?

Comment: ok I'll try removing App\Business

Comment: bro @STA you were always of great help, I did this and it worked! Thanks a lot man!

public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'unique:businesses,name,',
            'email' => 'email|unique:businesses,email,',
            'logo' => 'file|size:5000,',
            'banner' => 'file|size:5000,',
        ];  
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
      'name' => 'unique:businesses,name,' . $business->id,
      'email' => 'email|unique:businesses,email,' . $business->id,
      'logo' => 'file|size:5000,' . $business->id,
      'banner' => 'file|size:5000,' . $business->id,
      ];  
}
```

**For example** : *'name' => 'unique:businesses,name,' . $business->id,* 
**Explanation** : Here `businesses` is the table, where field is `name`, expect `id` = `$business->id`

See official documentations [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: I think I should make another request because when I tried to update it shows the error message "The business name has already been taken" even tho I didnt tried to change it. what do you think?

Comment: @AlphaChino **$business->id** is the `id` of **businesses** table, it will make validation without this `id`, so this validation is for update function. Not for store

Comment: I understand now. Thanks a lot @STA!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @STA

here's what worked

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'unique:businesses,name,',
        'email' => 'email|unique:businesses,email,',
        'logo' => 'file|size:5000,',
        'banner' => 'file|size:5000,',
    ];  
}
```